# Select from a table which might not exist

Tags: oracle, plsql

We have an issue that needs a bad hack to get around. Let me give you some context:

We have an app the overrides a customers configuration settings upon uninstalling/reinstalling it. It gets installed with default values, overriding any settings the customer put in.

The solution by management would be to create two scripts, one for each step:

1. Create a temporary table and copy over the configuration settings into it before uninstalling the app.
2. Once the app is re-installed, copy over the values from the temporary table back into the original table to retain their settings.

I'm not very fond of their solution, but I have to go with it.

I have step 1 down, but I'm having trouble dealing with the situation of running the second script (step 2) without the first script (step 1) being run before.

In essence, the temporary table would not be there when the second script compiles if someone else in a different department forgets to run the first one.

This is the code I'm currently using for the second script.

```
DECLARE
    lvnTableExists              NUMBER(1);
    lvbTempTableCopied          BOOLEAN;
    lvsTempTable                VARCHAR2(21) := 'TEMP_TABLE';
BEGIN
    -- CalcTypVarValue Table Copy
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO   lvnTableExists
    FROM   ALL_TABLES x
    WHERE  x.Table_Name = lvsTempTable ;

    IF lvnTableExists = 1 THEN
        FOR CalcRow IN (SELECT * FROM Temp_Table) LOOP -- Temp_Table will not exist if first script didn't run, causing a compile error
            UPDATE SomeOtherTable c
            SET    c.foo= CalcRow.foo,
                   c.bar= CalcRow.bar,
                   c.DateLastMaint = SYSDATE
            WHERE  c.bob= CalcRow.bob
            AND    c.bill= CalcRow .bill;
        END LOOP;
        lvbTempTableCopied    := TRUE;
    ELSE
        lvbTempTableCopied    := FALSE;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ...
    ...
```

My problem is that if `Temp_Table` doesn't exist at all, then I'll get a compile time error, so the script won't run at all. I need it to run so I can take action on whether to do something else if the table doesn't exist based on `lvbTempTableCopied`.

I've heard of bypassing it with something like `FOR CalcRow IN (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM ' || lvsTempTable)`, but I can't use it within a `FOR IN LOOP` like that.

How would I use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to bypass the compile time error?

Comment: Your count(*) should return 0 if table does not exist. In this case you need to raise an exception - like raise no_data_found and exit with some message. The rest of code should never be executed. The best way is not to use count(*) at all and let the exception be raised in select into part and you handle it.

Comment: @Art The script will not compile because `Temp_Table` would not exist. I am already handling the case where the table doesn't exist in my `EXCEPTION`, but the problem is the `Temp_Table` is preventing the script from even compiling. My problem, is that I don't know how to make it dynamic.

Comment: @Art - it's a compile-time error, not a run-time error; so just raising an exception won't help. It would need to be dynamic, as the OP suggested.

Comment: @Jimenemex - what client or tool will this be run with? There are non-dynamic options if you can rely on, say, SQL\*Plus error handling. Also, why are you using a loop instead of a single update?

Comment: @Alex Poole - thank you, Alex. I'm not suggesting this as the answer, just a comment.

Comment: @AlexPoole It would be run by our companies DBAs which use Oracle Database 12c

Comment: @Jimenemex - your count(*) will always return value and the rest of your code will be executed in any case. The best way is not using count(*) and let the exception be raised. Just a suggestion.

Comment: If it can be a single DML statement (or several), you could use `execute immediate` and catch the *table or view does not exist* exception. If it really needs to be a loop, you can still execute a PL/SQL block dynamically but it gets more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it dynamically using REF CURSOR, see sample code below,

```
DECLARE
    TYPE cur_typ IS REF CURSOR;
    c cur_typ;
    v_table_exists VARCHAR2(1);
    type temp1_rec is record (col1 VARCHAR2(100), col2 VARCHAR2(100));
    v_temp temp1_rec;
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Y'
      INTO v_table_exists
      FROM all_tables
     WHERE table_name = 'TEMP1';

     --dynamic query with parameters
     OPEN c FOR 'SELECT col1, col2 FROM temp1 WHERE :param1=:param2' USING 'PARAM1', 'PARAM1' ;
     LOOP
         FETCH c INTO v_temp;
         EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_temp.col1);
     END LOOP;  
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        NULL;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE TEMP1
(COL1 VARCHAR2(100),
 col2 VARCHAR2(100));

INSERT INTO temp1
VALUES('123123123asdfasdfsfa', 'JHASDKLFJLASDFLAS');
```